# PC requiements to use for Blender 2.8

Tags: hardware

I'm new to blender so please forgive the ignorance.
Can anyone tell me the optimum specifications for my PC I need to efficiently run blender 2.8.? 
Or would I do better to use a MAC.
I am a visual artist and I have not ventured into animation...yet 
Any advice would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Hello and wecome. Please search before posting, these questions can be found in the official documentation and have also been asked before and already have an answer See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122992/which-mac-should-i-buy-for-blender-2-8

Comment: Do what I did: Download it anyway and cross your fingers BECAUSE IT'S FREE!
Also, you won't get better specs here than you would get by reading what's available exactly where you think it is