# Mac Pro 2019 with Blender?

Tags: osx

I've planned to buy the new basic 2019 Mac Pro, essentially for use with blender. Is that a good idea? I own a mid2010 Mac Pro for now but it's a little bit slow as soon as there are a few textures in my projects.
...or should I switch on a Windows solution?
Thanks

Comment: It's not a good idea since OpenCL has been deprecated and the new versions of the CUDA Toolkit won't be released for macOS. Therefore the build-in render engines won't be able to leverage the GPU for rendering when using AMD graphics cards and in the near future the same will be the case for Nvidia graphic cards. This will be the case until Blender is ported to Vulkan and we have a MoltenVK or native Metal implementation of the render engines. A good workstation with either Windows or Linux will be more suitable.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158070/egpu-vega-56-blackmagic-mac-cycles-problem

Comment: Thanks. This is an interesting and precious info. For now (and next three months), do you know what should be the reasonable best choice as CPU and GPU?