# MacBook Pro not recognising Blackmagic eGPU for Blender

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have just upgraded to a new MacBook Pro with an external Blackmagic GPU with an AMD Pro Radeon 580 card, to use specifically to render in cycles for Blender 2.81 (I am too long in the Mac tooth to consider changing to PC). However Blender is not recognising or supporting the Blackmagic as an option....any advice?
I am running Catalina on a 2019 MBP 13" with 1.4Ghz quad-core Intel Core I5.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158070/egpu-vega-56-blackmagic-mac-cycles-problem