# Why blender don't see my GPU

Tags: rendering, gpu

I'm rendering my project with Cycles and if i go in Preferences - System - OpenCL
Blender don't see my GPU
I've an AMD Radeon HD 6770m 1024 mb and i'm using a 2011 Mac with a 3,1 GHz intel i5.

Answer (score 1):

There are three reasons why you can't use the AMD Radeon HD 6770M for GPU rendering on your system:

1. GPU rendering on macOS with an AMD card isn't possible since Blender 2.80, due to the deprecation of the OpenCL compiler by Apple (see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158071/74827) for more information).
2. The GPU is below the [minimum requirements for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#amd). The [AMD Radeon HD 6770M has the TeraScale 2 micro-architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#Radeon_HD_6000_series), but [GCN second generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview) is required on supported operating systems.
3. The GPU is below the [minimum requirements for running Blender 2.8x](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). Only AMD graphics cards with [GCN first generation or later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units#API_Overview) are officially supported.

Therefore, the GPU is neither suited for GPU rendering nor running Blender 2.8x on any operating system. You may have to use an [older version of Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/) with lower minimum requirements.